# C# missing assembly failover

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, failover

So I have a Windows Forms Application, which has some advanced features that depend on a 3rd party commercial library. Basically I want to implement a discount version of this library, and then use that as a failover if the big commercial one is not available, so that all functionality is available in the basic app, (it just looks nicer/performs better if you have the commercial library).

In Python you can do something like this:

```
try:
    import <dependency name>
except ImportError:
#   The dependency is unavailable.
```

Is there any similar functionality in C#? I've tried a similar approach (wrapping a using statement in a try/catch block) but that did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what functionality you speak of, it's more tricky if it's GUI components etc.

If it's just non visual code and classes then you can often just abstract the functionality to a higher level using things like interfaces and then load the relevant implementation as needed.

I've done this sort of thing with IoC before and it works pretty well for us.

Comment: Well basically I just want the application not to fail with a "Are you missing an assembly or reference" if the third party library is missing. I have all the code in place to handle switching between the two. What I need to do is have the application actually work when the assembly is missing, without having to build two separate binaries.

Using an Interface is not really an option (using Adapter/Wrapper Pattern instead) as the library I'm using is a 3rd party commercial library, so even if I did write an Interface, the third party library, would not implement it.